# How do I get a formula result from one cell, reflecting in a sentence in another cell?

Tags: microsoft-excel

In Microsof Excel: How do I get the result of a formula, to reflect in a sentence? For example: I have a calculation in cell A1. Now in A2, I have the following sentence: "The result is.... and is reflected on the schedule of differences" . I want the result from A1 to reflect in this sentence where the ...... is.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `&` to add strings and values together. For example:

```
= "The result is " & A1 & " and is reflected on the schedule of differences"
```

Comment: Depending on how you want to show the number you might also need TEXT, FIXED or ROUND function around A1 e.g. for 2 decimal places FIXED(A1,2)